# Paypal integration with socialEngine4.0 in php

Tags: php, zend-framework, paypal, socialengine

I am quite new to SocialEngine4.0 framework.I want to integrate SocialEngine application with paypal. Can any one suggest me is there any in built modules in socialengine to do Paypal integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SocialEngine already comes with a built-in PayPal integration. If you would like to use PayPal with your site, you will need to setup a PayPal Gateway. Instructions on how to setup a gateway can be found here: http://support.socialengine.com/questions/176/Admin-Panel-Billing-Gateways

If you will be using PayPal to create your own subscriptions for your site, then you will need to also setup a plan. Instructions can be found here:
http://support.socialengine.com/questions/177/Admin-Panel-Billing-Plans

If you are looking to use our built-in module for your own custom purpose. Then most of the module can be found in /application/modules/Payment